# How to get all array elements at depth in python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make a function which takes an array and returns the array sorted by the depth:

```
sortArrDepth([1, [5, 6], [4, 67, [34]], 7])
```

Would return

```
[[1, 7], [5, 6, 4, 67], [34]]
```

However, it has to be able handle arrays with any max depth and I would prefer to not use any external modules. If it helps, here is a function to get the max depth:

```
def getAstDepth(ast):
    depth = 0
    for i in last:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            depth = max(getAstDepth(i), depth)
    return depth
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using a recursive function:

```
def sortArrDepth(l, out=[], depth=0):
    if len(out)<=depth:
        out += [[] for _ in range(depth-len(out)+1)]
    for v in l:
        if isinstance(v, list):
            sortArrDepth(v, out=out, depth=depth+1)
        else:
            out[depth].append(v)
    return out
```

example:

```
>>> sortArrDepth([1, [5, 6], [4, 67, [34]], 7])
[[1, 7], [5, 6, 4, 67], [34]]

>>> sortArrDepth([1, [5, 6], [[[0]]], [4, 67, [34]], 7])
[[1, 7], [5, 6, 4, 67], [34], [0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` and recursion to get at the deeper levels:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def sort_by_depth(seq):
    first = [item for item in seq if not isinstance(item, list)]
    nested = [sort_by_depth(item) for item in seq if isinstance(item, list)]
    return [first] + [sum(item, start=[]) for item in zip_longest(*nested, fillvalue=[])]
```